# Add programmatically created layout in remoteview for Notification

Tags: android, android-layout, android-remoteview

I'm developing an application in which I have to not use custom layout for `notification`. Instead I have to use `programmatically` created layout for `RemoteViews`. Here is what I'm doing for layout stuff:

```
Notification notify = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("Notification")
            .setLargeIcon(
                    decodeBase64(NotificationImages.notification_ic_stat_notify))
            .build();

    LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(context);

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Drawable bg = new BitmapDrawable(
            decodeBase64(NotificationImages.search_bg));

    linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linLayout.setBackground(bg);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    linLayout.setLayoutParams(llp);

    ImageView icon = new ImageView(context);

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Drawable icon_bg = new BitmapDrawable(
            decodeBase64(NotificationImages.notification_logo));

    icon.setBackground(icon_bg);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams image_lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    image_lp.setMargins(20, 0, 0, 0);
    image_lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;

    icon.setLayoutParams(image_lp);

    linLayout.addView(icon);
```

Ignore the use of `base64` decoding, that I was doing for some random purpose.
So, right now what I want is to add this `layout` to `RemoteViews` for showing it on `notification panel`.
Something like this:

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(PACKAGE_NAME,
            R.layout.persistent_notification_layout);
```

How, can I replace the `layout.persistent_notification_layout` from the layout created programmatically?
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Here your LinearLayout and ImageView count is fixed. appear only 1 or more then that

Comment: Yes it is fixed, only one `Linear Layout`.

Comment: and what about ImageView? is also fixed?

Comment: i want to do same thing. i am adding  programmatically created layout in remoteview but its not working ...

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a step back, why do you "have to not use custom layout for notification", I'm not clear what that means. You then say "Instead I have to use programmatically created layout for RemoteViews." - why is that, what is it that you're doing that these are both true?  Perhaps if you could give a little more insight into what you're trying to accomplish, I could understand your goal and help you get to that point.

Comment: Hey Travis, actually I'm building a library jar file for android projects which will show up notification on `onCreate()`, as you know that jar file cannot have `drawables` or `layout` assets in them. So, to overcome that issue, I was thinking of implementing `remoteview` for `Notification` using program. Did you get my idea of why I wanted to use programmatically instead of using layout.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this question by not providing layout from the library file, but from the app which has included the library. I have added this function for creating notification layout.

```
public void searchBar(Context context, String packageName, int layout,
        String tickerText, int icon) {
```

As, you can see that all things are dynamic here with respect to the app, which are using this library. The layout and all the other stuff can be provided from the app itself.

Comment: this is not the true answer for the question. either change the question or solution you have provided. thanks in advance